# Swift Typhoon component property-injection doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, typhoon

i'm using swift with typhoon and somehow my components don't get injected through property-injection. For simple types like `Strings` it is working. I provided a simple example which explains the problem. The **Output** shows the result where `serviceB` has a null reference to `serviceA`. All `String` properties are set properly  and no error is thrown. What am i'm doing wrong here?

*XCode: 6-beta5 ,Typhoon: 2.1.0*

**MYServiceA.swift**

```
@objc(MYServiceA) public class MYServiceA : NSObject {

    public var text : String!

}
```

**MYServiceB.swift**

```
@objc(MYServiceB) public class MYServiceB : NSObject {

    public var text : String!
    public var serivceA : MYServiceA!

}
```

**MYAssembly.swift**

```
public class MYAssembly : TyphoonAssembly {

    public func serviceA() -> AnyObject {
        var definitionBlock : TyphoonDefinitionBlock = {(definition : TyphoonDefinition!) in
            definition.injectProperty("text", with: "some a text")
            definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton
        }
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(NSClassFromString("MYServiceA"), configuration: definitionBlock)
    }

    public func serviceB() -> AnyObject {
        var definitionBlock : TyphoonDefinitionBlock = {(definition : TyphoonDefinition!) in
            definition.injectProperty("text", with: "some b text")
            definition.injectProperty("serivceA", with: self.serviceA())
            definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton
        }
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(NSClassFromString("MYServiceB"), configuration: definitionBlock)
    }

}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {

        var assembly : MYAssembly = MYAssembly()
        var factory : TyphoonComponentFactory = TyphoonBlockComponentFactory(assembly: assembly) as TyphoonComponentFactory
        factory.makeDefault()

        var serviceA : MYServiceA = TyphoonComponentFactory.defaultFactory().componentForKey("serviceA") as MYServiceA
        println("MYServiceA")
        println("- instance=\(serviceA != nil)")
        println("- text=\(serviceA.text)")            

        var serviceB : MYServiceB = TyphoonComponentFactory.defaultFactory().componentForKey("serviceB") as MYServiceB
        println("MYServiceB")
        println("- instance=\(serviceB != nil)")
        println("- text=\(serviceB.text)")
        println("- serviceA.instance=\(serviceB.serivceA != nil)")            

        return true
    }
..
}
```

**Output**

```
MYServiceA
- instance=true
- text=some a text

MYServiceB
- instance=true
- text=some b text
- serviceA.instance=false
```

Comment: I haven't tried it with referenced components. I've raised an issue -> [Typhoon Issue](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/issues/243)

Comment: With Xcode6 beta6 we can add the dynamic attribute to a method. See updated answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typhoon assemblies make good use of the ObjC runtime's dyanmic dispatch features. Assemblies are reflected, and each method intercepted (applying an AOP 'around' advice) so that Typhoon has a blueprint to build each of the components in the app's assembly. However, Swift will try to use static/vtable dispatch where possible (which prevents the required method interception).

To instruct Swift that dynamic dispatch is required, mark your assembly methods as 'dynamic'.

**Example:** (Requires Xcode6 beta 6)

```
public class MYAssembly : TyphoonAssembly {

    public dynamic func serviceA() -> AnyObject {
        var definitionBlock : TyphoonDefinitionBlock = {
            (definition : TyphoonDefinition!) in

            definition.injectProperty("text", with: "some a text")
            definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton
        }
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(MYServiceA.classForCoder(), 
            configuration: definitionBlock)
    }

    public dynamic func serviceB() -> AnyObject {
        var definitionBlock : TyphoonDefinitionBlock = {
            (definition : TyphoonDefinition!) in

            definition.injectProperty("text", with: "some b text")
            definition.injectProperty("serivceA", with: self.serviceA())
            definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton
        }
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(MYServiceB.classForCoder(), 
            configuration: definitionBlock)
    }

}
```